# WPF C# Problem with image path between relative & absolute

Tags: c#, wpf, image, path

So at the moment I am working on a project for my diploma and developing a desktop application with Visual Studios and C#/WPF/XAML.
When I first started coding everything, I used for a relative path for the images, for example: "\Pics\background.jpg" in XAML. But then I always got an error

[image: (picture of error)]

when starting it up and wanting to show the page where the picture was in.
Therefore I always had to switch between relative and absolute path in order it to work.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Oh yeah, just so you know, the pictures are saved in this folder: "\Desktop\ePharmacy_v12\ePharmacy\Pics"
and I already tried to but the Pics folder into the debug folder etc. without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to click your image in Solution Explorer, and in properties of image set Build Action as "Resource" 
(click image -> Alt + Enter -> Advanced -> Build Action set to `Resource`)